# Bring back the original project from a WSDL file or a WAR file

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, war, wsdl2java

We have lost our java code that implement a web service. Now we have only a wsdl file (and a WAR file) published in tomcat. We need to bring back the original java project so I have tried to generate java source code from WSDL file (and WAR file) and I succeeded -by using axis2 (WSDL2JAVA) plugin- but I think it generates only the java classes that should exist in the src package of the project.. no welcome pages or index.xml etc.. I Don't know what other things are missing and how to bring them back.

My question is: what to do after generating java classes from WSDL file? should I complete the other project parts in my own? Is there a way to bring back exactly the original project from WSDL or WAR file?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Scenario you mentioned for WAR file you can use JAD tool to unpack the whole code but with certain limitations like you cannot edit or save the code and I am not sure about the copy feature because it was not working for previous version.

Here is the link below.
https://varaneckas.com/jad/